# And something you can show in a kind of vector representation. How you do this?

Tags: discussion

This question is in fact a meta question. I have less than 5 points of reputation on meta. So I can not ask this question on the meta.math.stackexchange.com. It reports: "You must have at least 5 reputation on to ask a question." I ask to migrate this question to meta.

Can a simple question: "Demonstrate with vectors that the sum of two vectors of equal modulus [length of vector], which phase changes between 0 and 180 degrees from each other, the square thereof increases from 0 to 4 times the vector length, and the phase will change from 0 to 90 degrees." be on-topic ?

And on the other hand, as in:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280355/given-with-the-log-base-10-common-logarithm-just-because-10-log-4-6-db

be off topic, although tagged ‘physics’ ?

If one consider: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7YJn_sAk1ZLSkR4eUt2Tk5fMUE/edit

It provide details.

Is it in that context less off-topic ?

Comment: The main problem is that that question is filled with non-mathematical terms. If you want to ask a math physics question, you still have to ask a math question, and it is always better to lead with the math, and then explain the possible physics aspects if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

The question referred to might as well have been closed for other reasons:

- **not a real question:** The title asks "... How can I demonstrate Task3?" whereas the body concludes "And Yes, I can demonstrate task 3."
- or **too localized**